# How to track app ad revenue in a mobile Unity game, for Facebook Ads

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have a Unity game with Facebook's SDK integrate for tracking in app purchases and it seems to be working alright. I want to now also track in-app ad revenue, so I could better track my ROAS, since right now it only takes into account IAP revenue.

When I track IAP revenue I use this kind of command:

```
FB.LogPurchase(e.purchasedProduct.metadata.localizedPrice, e.purchasedProduct.metadata.isoCurrencyCode);
```

Initially, when I wanted to also track ad revenue, I thought about using a line like this

```
FB.LogAppEvent("EVENT_NAME_AD_IMPRESSION", singleImpressionValue);
```

but it was unclear to me if/how I should add the currency code, and ultimately, I figured out this kind of app event will NOT be taken into account with ROAS.

So the only alternative I could think of, is to track it as purchases like so:

```
FB.LogPurchase(singleImpressionValue, currencyCode);
```

But this seems to be wrong to me as while it might track revenue more accurately, the number of purchases will be greatly exaggerated, as each ad impression will be counted as a purchase.

Am I missing something? Is there a chance that there's no proper way of tracking ad impression revenue for proper ROAS calculations?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While the number of purchase events will be increased hugely when you send ad impressions as purchases in FB, there won't be a problem with it and in case you are using ROAS goal campaigns, FB algorithm will work fine based on the value sets that it does define.
There is no other way to send ad events to FB and include them in the ROAS calculations, as **the only event that Facebook uses for the ROAS calculation is the Purchase event.**